# AsyncTask inside onPostExecute of AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In an Android activity I'm executing an AsyncTask in onCreate method.
Should I declare the handler function of UI buttons inside onPostExecute of AsyncTask or in OnCreate method? Can I create another AsyncTask inside this button onClick handler? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of code would be helpful to better answer you. But the call to the constructor or the `execute()` method can be done in `onCreate()` but the actual class should be created either in a separate file or as an inner class of your `Activity`, depending on what you need it for. What you are explaining would probably work but I wouldn't put `onClick` events in your `AsyncTask`. If nothing else, for the readability. Also, this may make it more error prone, in my opinion. You might need local variables outside of the `AsyncTask` for the `onClick()` so this would reduce scope issues. Calling an `AsyncTask` from inside an `onClick()` would generally be fine to do. I hope this makes sense but if you need more clarification feel free to ask